# Why `-moz-full-screen-ancestor` Custom Property is needed by HTML5 Video In Full Screen?

Tags: html, css, firefox, html5-video

Why `:-moz-full-screen-ancestor` necessary in firefox to display perfect result? 
All of the other browsers are working very well without this code.

```
#skinn:-moz-full-screen-ancestor {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Demo:** http://www.athimannil.com/player/

Answer (score 0):

These are called `vendor-specific prefixes` and they are used by developers to enhance features and add nice touches to objects.

They (`-moz prefixes`) were initially developed by Gecko when they couldn't fully support the use of the `full-screen` attribute, and other attributes like them. So they made a work-around version which you have used above.

Here's a webpage which i came across that might help you: http://davidwalsh.name/moz-css

Comment: at the same time this tutorial not using it http://css-tricks.com/custom-controls-in-html5-video-full-screen/

Comment: Yes, as i mentioned above, Gecko developed the `-moz` prefix back when they couldn't support it, now however, some of those attributes are being supported hence some newer sources are not using the `-moz` prefix.